# Iterate through 2 arrays containing objects and return the values of a second array using the first arrays keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, array.prototype.map

I'm trying to user `.map()` to map over 2 arrays and return a result array with new keys and values using existing keyvalues of arr1

I'm using the following arrays

```
arr1 = [
    {"name":"orange","mappedHeader":"dollar"},
    {"name":"apple","mappedHeader":"coin"}
];

arr2 = [
    {"orange":"red","pumpkin":"white","apple":"yellow", "plum":"green"},
    {"orange":"pink","pumpkin":"brown","apple":"gold","plum":"blue"},
];

whatIWant = [
    {"dollar":"red", "coin":"yellow"},
    {"dollar":"pink", "coin","gold"}
];
```

I've tried using `.map()` and `.filter()` but I don't seem to be implementing it right

please help

Comment: post the code you tried as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

arr1 contains mapped fields and headers

```js
var arr1 = [
    {"name":"orange","mappedHeader":"dollar"},
    {"name":"apple","mappedHeader":"coin"}
];
```

arr2 contains objects those we'll transform

```js
var arr2 = [
    {"orange":"red","pumpkin":"white","apple":"yellow", "plum":"green"},
    {"orange":"pink","pumpkin":"brown","apple":"gold","plum":"blue"},
];
```

Solution

```js
//var whatIWant = [
//    {"dollar":"red", "coin":"yellow"},
//    {"dollar":"pink", "coin","gold"}
//];

var whatIWant = arr2.map(item=>{ /* Step 1*/
    let obj = {};
    arr1.forEach((v,i,a)=>obj[v.mappedHeader] = item[v.name]); /* Step 2 */
    return obj; /* Step 3 */
})
```

step by step

- Use .map(...) for iterate objects
- Use forEach(...) for map each field into new empty object, taking value from item `item[v.name]` and set new field with that value with *mappedHeader* property name, `obj[v.mappedHeader] = ...`
- return obj as new object for new returning list/array